# T-sql Concatenate variables for use in an Insert Into while loop

Tags: t-sql, variables, while-loop, concatenation

I'm trying to create a SQL statement that allows me to save time when creating a series of CTEs or temp tables that are all the same and only increment in certain places. I could do this with VBA, but I can't figure out if this is possible with SQL

I'm trying to run the following code

```
DECLARE @N as INT
DECLARE @POINTS as TABLE(ID int Not Null,n varchar(3) Not Null)
DECLARE @TABLENAME varchar(6)

Set @INC = 1
Set @N = 5

--WHILE @INC <= @N
--BEGIN

Declare @N1 INT
Declare @N2 INT
Declare @N3 INT
Declare @N4 INT
Declare @N5 INT
SET @N1=25
SET @N2=50
SET @N3=100
SET @N4=250
SET @N5=500
--END

WHILE @INC <= @N
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @POINTS(ID, n) 
        VALUES (@INC, CONCAT('@N',@INC))
        SET @INC = @INC + 1
    END

Select * from @POINTS
```

These are the results of the code after it runs:

```
ID  n
1   @N1
2   @N2
3   @N3
4   @N4
5   @N5
```

Is it possible to have the values I set for each @Nx variable be inserted to the n column instead of the concatenated character values? If so, how? I haven't been able to find any results on someone trying to do this.

I can get around this problem by using outside tables, but I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: This entire thing smells like a mistake. SQL is not a programming language and using loops is almost never the correct solution in this world. I'm not sure *why* you want "a series of CTEs or temp tables that are all the same and only increment in certain places" but I can pretty much guarantee that it's the wrong way to solve what ever problem you might be facing. This seems very much like an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: I'm looking at using a loop because I want to reduce rework time when I need to make changes. I already wrote this as a traditional SQL statement that works. The problem is that when I want to make changes, I have to touch five different table definitions that are identical in every way except the naming. I'm literally using NotePad++ and using the replace tool to make changes to the code and then copy/pasting

Comment: "I have to touch five different table definitions that are identical in every way except the naming." That right there is a sign of a poor database design (with the exception of temporal or simple Id-to-name translation tables). If you have more than one table to describe a single business entity - that's a problem in your database design.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the database design, I'm pulling different counts of test values from an existing database so I can see how the capability statistics behave over time. About the only thing changing is the count of N for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a small number of values values, you might as well write a single insert statement that will insert all 5 rows to the table:

```
INSERT INTO @POINTS(ID, n) VALUES 
(1, '5'), 
(2, '25'), 
(3, '50'),
(4, '100'),
(5, '250'),
(6, '500');
```

If you have too many values to write like this, you can use a cte to generate an inline tally table, and use `insert...select` from that tally table:

```
DECLARE @Points as TABLE
(
    ID int Not Null,
    n varchar(3) Not Null
);

WITH E10(N) AS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))V(N)
), Tally(N) AS
(
    -- Since all the numbers are multiples of 5, 
    -- there's no point of populating the tally
    -- with numbers that aren't multiples of 5....
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) * 5
    FROM E10 As Ten
    CROSS JOIN E10 As Hundred
    --Need more? Add more cross joins 
    -- each will multiply the number of rows by 10:
    --CROSS JOIN E10 As Thousand
    --CROSS JOIN E10 As [Ten Thousand] -- and so on    
)

INSERT INTO @Points(ID, n) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY N), CAST(N as varchar(3))
FROM Tally
WHERE N IN(5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500);

SELECT *
FROM @Points;
```

Results:

```
ID  n
1   5
2   25
3   50
4   100
5   250
6   500
```

Of course, if you already have a tally table, you don't need the cte...